# How can I electrically isolate two 24 VAC sprinkler controllers working on the same output (master valve)?

Tags: isolation, low-voltage, home-automation

I have an old 24-zone sprinkler controller and I'm trying to move 16 zones to a "smart" sprinkler controller. I have a master valve that has to be switched on to provide water downstream to the other zone valves 1-24. In this case the old controller and the new second controller will both have to be wired to turn on the same master valve and will share a common ground wire.

The manufacturer of the smart controller recommends to use a $45 "isolator" per controller to protect them. I was thinking I could use diodes for isolation. Any ideas? $90 for isolators is more than I payed for the controller, I'd rather put something together myself, but I am not sure where to start.

I could put the master valve on a separate power source and use solid state relays to trigger the master valve. Is that even necessary?

Comment: Without implementation detail of the system, you have to assume the worst - eg use relays, or even simply use two valves in parallel so each system has an independent way of turning on the water.  In being so intimately dependent on the unknowable behavior of undocumented products, this is more of an off-topic usage question than an on-topic design question.

Comment: If you draw it out, I think you will see that since they are the same voltage, and sharing a common "neutral" wire, that it should be easy to wire them directly.  The triacs will block the voltage from other device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fomXKs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. New configuration schematic.

You just need two 24 V AC relays. Power one from the original controller and one from the other. Wire a contact of each in parallel to turn on the master solenoid.

Comment: thanks! should I use SPNO?

Comment: I found an off the shelf solution for $7 based off your advice, does this look right?
https://ueeshop.ly200-cdn.com/u_file/UPAH/UPAH371/1903/products/08/e7853d63ff.jpg

Comment: That should do the job.